# merging Linq queries

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, ninject

Could someone explain me what will happen when I execute this query

I'm using (read learning) ninject and have following code

```
public interface IProducts
{
    IQueryable<Product> Products { get; }

   //some functions

}
```

I have following class "Product" which implements IProducts interface

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }

    public IQueryable<Product> Products
    {
        get
        {
            using(/*Connect to dtabase*/)
            {
                var products = from p in db.Products
                               select p;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have added

```
ninjectKernel.Bind<IProducts>().To<Product>();
```

I wonder what will happen if I have added another Linq query like `where product.Name == Something`

For example

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    private IProducs repository;

    public ProductController(IProducts products)
    {
         repository = products;
    }

    public ViewResult Find(string productName)
    {
          var product = from p in repository
                         where p.Name == productName
                         select p;
     }
}
```

Far as I know Linq query will execute only when I loop trough data so I wonder if these two Linq queries will merge into one.

For example

```
from p in db.Products
where p.Name == Something
select p;
```

Could someone confirm me if I got it right

Comment: In your `IQueryable<Product> Products` property you create and dispose a new context. In other words you return an `IQueryable` that references a disposed context. This will fail. The context can not be disposed at that point. Furthermore, you must reuse the same context when you want to combine multiple `IQueryable`s.

Comment: You should rename your `IProducts` to `IProductRepository`. That is the correct terminology of what that is. This makes it easier for other developers to understand what its function is.

Comment: "so I wonder if these two Linq queries will merge into one". Why don't you try this out? You can use the SQL Profiler to see what query is sent to the database.

Comment: I sow some EF examples about using ninject and tried to implement it in LINQ to SQL. I'll try it out as separate project but dont really understand what should I do to make it only one query

Comment: I you want to use dependency injection with the repository pattern, take a look at [this article](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=84). It describes an effective way of implementing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler will *effectively* transform your declarative LINQ statements into method calls. (I say *effectively* because it's really down to compiler internals whether method translation actually takes place or whether it 'shortcuts' straight to IL - this is not important for us to know in this context.)

I.e. :-

```
from p in db.Products
    select p;
```

represents

```
db.Products.Select(p => p);
```

and

```
from p in repository.Products    // .Products is missing in your code
    where p.Name == productName
    select p
```

represents

```
repository.Products.Where(p => p.Name == productName);
```

Now, *since execution is deferred*, when we enumerate our final value ('loop through data'), the following will effectively be executed:-

```
db.Products.Select(x => x).Where(p => p.Name == productName);
```

It is then down to the specific implementation of `IQueryable<T>` (`db.Products`) to translate this to whatever is appropriate. In the case of the Linq2SQL provider, this will be something like:-

```
SELECT
    P.Name, P.Foo, P.Bar, ...
FROM
    Product P
WHERE
    P.Name = "the name you specify"
```

So you see, due to deferred execution, the translation to a single query against the database is done for you. You don't have to take any special action to make this happen.

Comment: You're welcome. I think it's much easier to think about this kind of thing if you consider the operations represented as method calls instead of declarative LINQ syntax. It's one of the reasons I prefer to write my code as method calls. In fact, I don't use the declarative LINQ syntax at all.